# How to find maximum of n elements in an unsorted array n times?After each time the value of one element is decreased by n in linear fashion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, max

Example: The array at the beginning is `6 6 9 7` where `n=4`.

**Initial Array: 6 6 9 7

First max: 9

Array changes to: 6 6 9 3   (since arr[3]-4=3)

Second max: 9

Array changes to: 6 6 5 3   (since arr[2]-4=5)

Third max: 6

Array changes to: 6 2 5 3   (since arr[1]-4=2)

Fourth max: 6

Array changes to: 2 2 5 3   (since arr[0]-4=2)**

This could be easily achieved in O(n^2) but can it be done more efficiently?
Here is the code for O(n^2) solution:

```
int arr[]={6,6,9,7};
int n=4;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   int max=0;
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
       if(arr[j]>arr[max])
            max=j;
   }
   System.out.println(arr[max]);
   arr[n-1-i]-=n;
 }
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Do you want to return the individual modified arrays? Or do you just want to return the final modified array? Show us your O(n^2) algorithm, or give us a bit more detailed requirements.

Comment: just those max values not the modified array

Comment: i am just subtracting n from array cell one by one starting from last cell.After that finding maximum at each step. @JimMischel

Comment: added my code @JimMischel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in O(n log n) if you construct a separate data structure that consists of a max heap and an index. The idea is that you could then step through the index in reverse order, each time adjusting the value of the node in the max heap, and then moving it up or down through the heap. The root element of the heap would always contain the current maximum number. This solution would require O(n) extra memory.

If you want to do this in-place with O(1) extra memory, you can make the best case time O(n) by keeping track of the maximum element, and only searching for the new max when the maximum element changes. That would slightly improve the average case, but the worst case would still be O(n^2).